# Selecting rows with distinct column values using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sharepoint

I have a generic list of SharePoint list items (List employees)

The SharePoint list contains the two columns, "Employee Name" and "Employee Designation"

I want to get an object List which contains distinct "Employee Designation" column values.

How do I do this using LINQ?

This didnt work for me:

```
 var designations = from SPListItem employee in employees
                    select new {Designation = employee["Employee Designation"].ToString().Distinct()};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are only retrieving the string value of that column, you can avoid writing an equality comparer by selecting a string (instead of an object containing a string property).

```
var designations = (from SPListItem employee in employees
                    select employee["Employee Designation"].ToString())
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: How would you get only items the user has permission to view?

Comment: @JAck28, it turns out to be the case that SharePoint respects permission settings regardless of which API (Web, SOAP, ODATA, Server OM, CSOM, ODBC, etc) is being used. That means that whichever query was used to obtain the collection `employees` was already security-trimmed. The only case where this statement might not be true is if you use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPermissions()` to bypass the security permissions of the end user. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Distinct method on the sequence, and you will need to provide a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`, because of this you will need an explicit class for the object you are creating.

```
var designations = (from SPListItem employee in employees
                   select new 
                   {
                     Designation = employee["Employee Designation"].ToString()
                   }).Distinct(comparer);
```